# Request.getParameter() not working in jsp page using CQ

Tags: jsp

I have a code like below

```
<div>
  <form action="<%= currentNode.getPath() %>.html" method="POST">
         <input type="text" name="test" id="test"/>
         <input type="submit" name="submitt" id="submitt" style="display:none;" /> 
     </form>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the value of the field test

```
<%
String name=request.getParameter("test"); 
out.println("value in the string"+name);
%>
```

But I get only null value? What could be the issue?

Comment: <div><form action="<%= currentNode.getPath() %>.html" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="test" id="test"/>
<input type="submit" name="submitt" id="submitt" style="display:none;" /> 
     </form></div>

Comment: <% String name=request.getParameter("test"); out.println("value in the string"+name); %>

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="<%= currentNode.getPath() %>.html" method="POST">
```

Are you posting the form to `html` page . And how can you get the result in the html page

your `form action` attribute should have the url of the servlet or another jsp in order to get the values from the request .

`Request` is the implicit object of jsp and not the html.

For ex,

**one.jsp:**

```
        <form name="form1" action="two.jsp" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="test" id="test"/>
         <input type="submit" name="submitt" id="submitt" style="display:none;" /> 
        </form>
```

**two.jsp:**

```
<%
String name=request.getParameter("test"); 
out.println("value in the string"+name);
%>
```

will print you the value in the request . rather if you are trying to get the value in the same page without posting it . can achieve it using `javascript`

Comment: Even when i remove the html it doesn't work<div>
     <body onload="form1.submit();">


     <form name="form1" action="<%= currentNode.getPath() %>" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="test" id="test"/>
         <input type="submit" name="submitt" id="submitt" style="display:none;" /> 
     </form>
     </body>

 </div>

Comment: Do you want to get the id in the same page or you are trying to post in the different one

Comment: In the same Page but in scriptlet or JSTL tags but not in javascript

Comment: I have a value in my javascript and i am trying to take the value in my jsp page. To do that i created a form.

Comment: If you still have any clarifications join here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63539/jsp-concepts

Comment: If i want the same page to be loaded what should i do ? Can i gave one.jsp itself in the action. I am not able to join the chat. What you sent was very useful

Comment: If you want to display the data in same page without posting entire thing you should do the call in ajax. see my recent answer on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524067/get-servlet-attribute-without-loading-current-jsp-page/26524367#26524367

Comment: If i want it to be loaded in the same page. Can i give action with the same jsp name ?? ie. One.jsp itself. When i try like that it loads some html with one.jsp as a suffix in the url