# get servlet attribute without loading current jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

on my servlet I have this code :

```
processRequest(...,...){

String page = "";
if(true){
String str = "hello";
request.setAttribute("str",str);
page = "currentPage#";
}
else{
page = "otherPage";
}
RequestDispatcher rd = requestDispatcher("/",page);
}
```

on my JSP, to get the servlet attribute,I use this :

```
<input type = "text" value = "<c out>${str}</c out>">
```

This what happens,

when I use `currentPage#` the current page do not load, but `input` tag always have a value of `null`,

but if I used `currentPage`(without the #), I get the **"hello"** value the page loads,which i do not want to happen because the page and it contents will refresh.

Can somebody help me to get `str attribute` without loading the currentpage or is there any way?

Comment: why dont you try it out with Ajax . As you dont want to reload your page

Comment: Im not knowledgable in ajax, can you give example?

Answer (score 2):

use jQuery and you could simply get this done via jQuery.ajax();
Let's say you have a text input:

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
```

From your Servlet, return your required String:

```js
String empName = "Test Coder";
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(empName);
```

and you can call your onClick function like this:

```js
$("#search").on("click", function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YOUR SERVLET NAME",
    data: "{empid: " + empid + "}", // what ever the data you need to pass to server to generate yout "String"

    success: function(result) {
      alert(result.empName); // this should be your String parameter returned from the Servlet. 
       
      $("search").val(str);  // setting the String value on your text input
      
      console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {

      console.log("error" + error);
    }
  });

});
```

This is just a sample, I did not try it.. hope this will give you a clear path to achieve your target..! try and let us know.

Comment: oops, my question is not clear, what I need is to get servlet attribute using jquery or javascript, not sending data from jsp page to servlet

Comment: I try your code, but this doesnt work  alert(result.empName);

Comment: It may not work, what I just wanted to show you the process, how you should update your page values without refreshing the page using jquery ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You a load a part of your page using Ajax. It is even made easier using jquery

For ex ,

**JSP:**

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userName').blur(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'GetUserServlet',
            tpye: "POST",
            data : {
                userName : $('#userName').val()
            },
            success : function(responseText) {
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>     
        <form>
            Enter Your Name: <input type="text" id="userName" />
        </form>
        <br>
        <br> 
        <strong>Ajax Response</strong>:
        <div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse"></div>
```

And in your servlet,

```
String userName = request.getParameter("userName").trim();
        if(userName == null || "".equals(userName)){
            userName = "Guest";
        }

        String greetings = "Hello " + userName;         
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().write(greetings);
```

On the submitting the from in the jsp , only your `ajaxGetUserServletResponse` will be refreshed presenting the data from the server .

[Learn more](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: whats with "js/app-ajax.js" ?, can i work ajax without any another js file to include?